# Alternative way to dismiss a view controller without calling self.dismissViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to dismiss (and deallocate) a view controller (preferably in Swift) without calling `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated`?

I tried the following method and it doesn't really do it:

```
let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true) {
    //self.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.tabBarController!.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to call `dismissViewController`? It is the logical way to dismiss it after calling `presentViewController`. If you don't want the animation you can always pass `animated: false`.

Comment: try `poptorootviewcontroller` or `poptoviewcontroller`

Comment: Because I have a loginVC that is the Root view controller ONLY if the user has used the app before. Otherwise it is my TabVC. So if the user have used the app before and pressed Logout, the dismissViewController code will not work because the rootVC is not my login screen (It would be my tabVC).

Answer (score 3):

`dismissViewController:animated` should be used to dismiss a view controller which was presented with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Similarly, `popViewControllerAnimated:` method of UINavigationController is used to pop a view controller shown with `pushViewController:animated`.

Answer (score 2):

In my iOS applications, I reset the root view controller of the application window on logout. Doing this will remove all previous view controllers from memory, and present your loginVC. Here's an example in swift:

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginVC =   mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

Comment: Why would setting the rootViewController to be loginVC remove all other VC from memory? Also one stupid question, how do I check what VC lives in the memory? Thanks

Comment: They are being removed from memory because you are removing the current application window hierarchy and setting a new root. If this is difficult to understand, think of your application window as a navigation controller. What you are doing is removing every controller in the navigation controller and setting a new root. This will force every other controller to deallocate. To check what lives in memory, do product - >profile. Then when the instruments panel appears, choose the Allocations option. As your are using your app, you can search for your VC and make sure it is being removed.

Comment: i m apply above code for push but i want pop means back view controller what should i do ..